# Here maps free evaluation iOS mobile SDK for 90 days, no link available on the web to download

Tags: sdk, here-api

As part of our mobile app development we need to work on offline maps. Recently we have registered for HERE maps iOS free evaluation sdk(90 days), however we are not able to download HERE maps sdk and explained samples since there is no download link available on website(https://developer.here.com/native-apis). We have sent several mails to support team but nobody responded to my mails.

Someone help us to proceed further like how to get this sdk, so that we can integrate this free evaluation HERE sdk in our apps. If we are happy with this maps we are ready to purchase business license also.

Note: Google Maps(no offline), Skobbler maps are giving sdks and sample programs but not Here Maps.

Comment: Can you clarify your issue? Is there a specific error your getting?

Comment: Sorry If I am not able to write it clearly... I just want to download the Here maps iOS SDK, for that I need download link. Currently download link is no where available on the website. They have written like I need fill the request form to get access to the mentioned SDK. I have submitted that request form several times in this page(https://developer.here.com/contact-us) but I haven't got any reply. I personally sent emails also but no luck. I just wanted to test this SDK if it is OK we are ready to buy licence also. But I am not getting response from HERE maps team. Hope this time I'm clear.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a support question to be clarified with the provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native HERE Maps SDK which includes offline map support can now be evaluated by anyone, no business license required. You just need to create a HERE account and request an evaluation copy.

Go to developer.here.com > Mobile SDKs > Sign up for a 90-day free trial

https://developer.here.com/native-apis

Answer (score 1):

I contacted HERE a few days ago. They said that the SDK is available only for business contracts, not for free contracts. And it's not possible to get the sdk for evaluation. We need first a business contract...

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. How did you contacted them, If possible could you please give me the reference numbers or mail IDs...

Comment: The address is selfservesupport_amer@here.com.

Comment: It is mentioned in the welcome email "Welcome to HERE Platform" when creating an account and an app.

Comment: After that, depending on your country, you are forwarded to other addresses.

Comment: How to enter a line break in a comment... ?

Comment: The other addresses are selfservesupport_apac@here.com and selfservesupport_emea@here.com

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the below link to download Here maps mobile SDKs for android and iOS:

   https://developer.here.com/plans/mobile-sdk
2. Currently there are two types of mobile SDKs are available

1.Starter Evaluation(90-day free trial) : Some feature will not be available here.

For ex a).We cannot download maps with this. 
   b).Hybrid mode will not work here etc.

Hybrid version will work both online and offline modes whereas online version will only work in online mode. You can download the maps with Here mobile SDK and then you can navigate to the places without internet. In hybrid version app will switch to offline automatically whenever net is not available.

2.Premium Evaluation(90-day free trial) : We can download maps.